# How should the YAML look to use a Docker container (sidecar service) in my build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I manage to use them fine as long as I don't need to pass custom arguments.

Lets say I want to use an official Docker image: `somePublicImage:1.2.3`; then the following works fine:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTestPack
    displayName: 'Build, test & pack'
    timeoutInMinutes: 5
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2
    services:
      someService:
        image: somePublicImage:1.2.3
        ports:
        - 4223:4222
```

There's an option to configure the container with `--foo bar`

How do I define this in a Azure build pipeline?

I've tried:

- command
- options
- arguments
- entrypoint

Comment: `options` should work, per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#other-settings. What YAML have you tried with `options`, and what errors do you get?

Comment: The `options` are passed to `docker create`so you can use it for setting switches that `docker create` supports not to pass custom arguments to the container it self. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/

Answer (score 0):

Service containers must define a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. The pipeline will `docker run` the provided container without additional arguments.

Check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Seen that but how do I set a "custom" cmd or entrypoint in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to create a "custom" resource container first. E.g

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: myThing
    image: somePublicImage:1.2.3
    ports:
    - 4223:4222
    volumes:
    - /docker_vol_config:/config
    command: '--foo bar'
```

which then can be used as a service:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTestPack
    displayName: 'Build, test & pack'
    timeoutInMinutes: 5
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2
    services:
      myThing:myThing
```